# I need to resize pictures according to the visitors viewport

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Folks, please be gentle, I am not a professional programmer, just a site admin and I need some help. Here is my problem:

I am running a web site, with php. I would like to show pictures to my members, but I would like those pictures to remain within specific size limits, so they do not cause the visitors to scroll horizontally in order to view the whole picture. So far, I have limited the size of uploaded pictures to 800x600 as a least common denominator. However, I believe that users with larger monitors should be allowed to see larger pictures, so I plan to remove that 800x600 limit, but I still would like to make sure that the image displayed wouldn't be larger than the visitor viewport (actually let's say 2/3's of the viewport).

Now, I understand that php runs on the server and javascript runs on the client and that there is no easy way to pass the viewport dimensions to the php code, I tried and failed miserably, so that is clear.

But I've also read (especially in this site) that there are ways to do it, using JQuery and/or Ajax. My main problem? I do not know how to program in Javascript, JQuery or Ajax. So my question is: What exactly should I include in my php file to cause the client to return the browser width to the php file or my html template, in order to use the browser width in the  statement my program generates?

If I understand this right, when a visitor asks to see a page and my server send them the result of my page, there should be some code, which will send me back the browser width, then the server will resend the page, using the value it received. Am I correct in that? If that's the way it works, it would be ideal if I could get that browser width value and store it in a php global variable, so that not every page is generated twice. Can that be done?

Please be very specific, as I said, I am a newbie on these things.

Needless to say, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks for your attention.

P.S.: I have already download and installed JQuery in my server, but I have no idea how to use it for this problem.

Comment: if you don't mind the browser scaling the image, you could achieve this with css alone. No server-side scaling needed.

Comment: you can place % values for img tags from css

Comment: I really can't fathom why people are so quick to downvote these days. So @downvoter, you might want to leave a comment for otherwise there is no way to improve the question.

Comment: Personally upvoted to counter the un-commented downvote this question received.  The question is reasonably presented and clearly conveys intent.  @Downvoter - why?

Comment: I dont see any reason why its downvoted. Upvoted to counter it.

Comment: @Yoshi - You should (could*) throw your comment in as an answer with some links to CSS width and max-width?

Comment: @Smudge202 I'll leave that to kiranvj. The answer is allready on the right track. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try `style="max-width:100%;"`

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/5HeG2/1/

Comment: OK, css seems to be another option, and perhaps simpler. So I can simply add a "style='max-width:75%" in my <IMG> statement?

Comment: There is one problem with the above style="max-width:85%" statement. It sets the max width of the picture to 85% (or whatever) of the maximum monitor resolution, not the 85% of the browser window width. Is there another parameter that I can use in the style definition to get the image to be 85% of the browser window width?

Comment: Its not respective of the monitor resoultion, % is with respect to the container in with the image is placed. So if you give 85% it will 85% of the width of the parent container. Try this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5HeG2/3/

Comment: Well, I tried it and while my browser window was much less than 1800px, the program resized the image to 1850 or something. I think I've managed to solve my issue by using a "style="width:85%;" instead. Does that look correct?

Comment: >> style="width:85%; In that case the height should also be propotional, otherwise the image will look distroted. Or create a div with some width and place the image inside that.

Comment: Strange, the image dimensions remain correct when I use width only, it doesn't need a height declaration. I think I have found the solution to my problem, thanks a lot.

Comment: It will scale proportionally if you don't provide the height attribute in the img tag. Fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/5HeG2/5/  btw: new info for me also :)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this simple snippet to get things started for you. As you said you needed to resize the image as per the client size and you mentioned that you would be looking for something related to ajax/jquery.

I use here a image resizing/caching script available from [github](https://github.com/whizzzkid/phpimageresize) to load a sample image upto 80% of the available browser width.

without much ado:

1. index.php

   ```
   <html>
   <head>
       <script>
       function getImg(img){
           if (img==""){
               return;
           }
           width = screen.availWidth;
           if (window.XMLHttpRequest){// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
               xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
           }else{// code for IE6, IE5
               xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
           }
           xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
               if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
                   document.getElementById("img_div").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
               }
           }
           xmlhttp.open("GET","resizer.php?i="+img+"&w="+width,true);
           xmlhttp.send();
       }
       </script>
   </head>
   <body>
       <center>
       <div id="img_div" style="left:0px; top:0px; height: 100%; width:100%;">
               <a href="#" onClick="getImg('xyz.jpg');">Show The Image</a>
       </div>
       </center>
   </body>
   ```
2. resizer.php

   ```
   <?php
   //resizing library
   include 'function.resize.php';

   $i = $_GET['i'];
   $w = $_GET['w'];
   echo "Image Requested: ".$i." ; Client's Browser Width: ".$w."px";
   $w = 0.8*$w;
   echo " ; We will show 80% of width: ".$w."px";
   $i_settings['w'] = $w;
   echo '<img src="'.resize($i,$i_settings).'" />';
   ?>
   ```
3. function.resize.php from [github](https://github.com/whizzzkid/phpimageresize)
4. The Image you want ([in our case it is a 1920x1080 one](http://clients.nishantarora.in/projects/user1517199/xyz.jpg))

Now the code is pretty much self explanatory. But things can get a bit confused at times. So [CLICK HERE](http://clients.nishantarora.in/projects/user1517199) to see the working example and tell me is this something of a solution you were looking for?

Hope I helped!
Regards

Comment: Thanks for this, appreciated. At the moment, I am facing some problems after moving my sites to a new server, and I can't spend time for the picture resizing issue. So it will have to wait, until I solve the other problems. Many thanks though!!